# Make button clickable after state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I have this count where I will increment once the `button with handleFollow()` is clicked **(i have multiple buttons with handleFollow() and I'm only showing one here)**. How do keep track of the count and then change the `allowNext to false` once the count is more than 3 so that I can make the button clickable.

```js
let count = 0;
const [allowNext, setAllowNext] = useState(true)
const [followed, setFollowed] = useState({
    1 : false,
    2 : false,
    3 : false,
    4 : false,
    5 : false,
  })

const handleFollow = (idx) => {
    const val = !followed[idx]
    setFollowed(prev => ({...prev, [idx] : val}))
    count += 1
}

<div>
     <Button onClick={() => {handleFollow(5);}} style={buttonStyle1} disabled={clicked[4]}>Continue</Button> 
</div>

// disabled={allowNext=false} only when count is more than 3 to make it clickable
<div>
     <Button style={buttonStyle2} disabled={allowNext} onClick={() => {setSelectedForm(2)}}>Next page</Button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define count as state first, and then you can add useEffect for this case

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    if (count > 3){ 
      setAllowNext(false);
    }

}, [count]);
```

And change the way you increment in handleFolow instead of `count += 1`, use `setCount(prev => prev+1)`

Alternative approach would be, keep count as state and keep setCount increment, but instead of useEffect, after you increment `count` you directly check

```js
if (count > 3){ 
  setAllowNext(false) 
}
```

However I am not sure if this is safe because we access directly after the changing the state, bug might occur, so first approach would be my way to go

Comment: Got it! I'm using the first approach and it worked! Thank you! :D

Comment: Great, accepting this answer as accepted answer would be helpful for me :)